# react-native navigationV3 integrating redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

My objective is to implement redux into my react-native proj. But it's not an error, it's unsuccessful. How can I organize my code such that it'll work?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ReduxNavigation from './src/navigation/ReduxNavigation';
import AppReducer from './src/reducers/index';
import { middleware } from './src/utils/redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { logger } from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import AppNavigation from './src/navigation/AppNavigation';
//import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

// create our store
const store = createStore(AppReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppNavigation />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

../utils/redux

```
import {
  createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware,
  reduxifyNavigator,
  createNavigationReducer,
} from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const middleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
  'root',
  state => state.nav
);
const App = reduxifyNavigator('root');
export { middleware, App };
```

../navigation/navReducer

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import AppNavigation from '../navigation/AppNavigation';

const firstAction = AppNavigation.router.getActionForPathAndParams(
  'initialStack'
);
const tempNavState = AppNavigation.router.getStateForAction(firstAction);

const initialNavState = AppNavigation.router.getStateForAction(tempNavState);

const nav = (state = initialNavState, action) => {
  let nextState;
  switch (action.type) {
    default: {
      nextState = AppNavigation.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
      break;
    }
  }
  return nextState || state;
};

export default nav;
```

../reducers/index

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import transactionsReducer from './transactionsReducer';
import setVisibilityFilter from './setVisibilityFilter';
import userReducer from './userReducer';
import AppNavigation from '../navigation/AppNavigation';
import { createNavigationReducer } from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers';    
import nav from './navReducer';

const navReducer = createNavigationReducer(AppNavigation);

const AppReducer = combineReducers({
  nav: navReducer,
  transactionsReducer,
  setVisibilityFilter,
  userReducer,
});

export default AppReducer;
```

../navigation/ReduxNavigation

```
import React from 'react';
import { addNavigationHelpers,StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {AppNavigation} from './AppNavigation';


class ReduxNavigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { dispatch, nav } = this.props;
    return (
      <AppNavigation
        navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
          dispatch,
          state: nav,
        })}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  nav: state.nav,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation);
```

../navigation/AppNavigation
//please consider all my screens to be dumb for transparency..

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Button, Icon } from 'native-base';
import InitialScreen from '../containers/InitialScreen';
//import ForgottenPasswordScreen from '../containers/ForgottenPassword';
import Transactions from '../containers/Transactions';
import Screen1 from '../containers/Screen1';
import Screen2 from '../containers/Screen2';
import Screen3 from '../containers/Screen3';
import SignIn from '../containers/SignIn';
import Accounts from '../components/Accounts';
import SignUp from '../containers/SignUp';

// drawer stack
const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator({
  screen1: { screen: Screen1 },
  screen2: { screen: Screen2 },
  screen3: { screen: Screen3 },
});

const DrawerNavigation = StackNavigator(
  {
    DrawerStack: { screen: DrawerStack },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'float',
  }
);

// login stack
const LoginStack = StackNavigator({
  transactionsScreen: { screen: Transactions },
});

const initialStack = StackNavigator({
  initialScreen: { screen: InitialScreen },
});

// Manifest of possible screens
export const AppNavigation = StackNavigator(
  {
    initialStack: { screen: initialStack },
    drawerStack: { screen: DrawerNavigation },
    loginStack: { screen: LoginStack },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    title: 'Main',
    initialRouteName: 'initialStack',
  }
);
```

I'm a beginner and it's highly likely my code structures could be wrong, but this is the basic idea. I have to use navigationV3.

Would someone go through this and advise me on my bad practices on the above code? I want to improve my coding style.

Would someone also create and share a boilerplate for the above scenario? EXPO compactable.

Comment: Why do you need to place your navigation into your redux store? In my experience this will give you more headaches than actual profit. Have a look at this page of the react-navigation documentation that explains this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html

Comment: I could be wrong, but i think your mapStateToProps is missing a return:
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
nav: state.nav,
}}; Also, can you put a console.log(state) inside the mapStateToProps, see what you'll get in return

Comment: considering, #needsleep's recommendation(that comes from experience), i've decided to use navigation without  state. now, everything works fine. but someday i'd have to do it for some reason so the thread is still open..